# Returning multiple matches from a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am having difficulties with a basic program I am trying to write with a 2d array. I'm trying to make it so that if the search matches multiple results, all relevant results are returned. In this case, I'm trying to make "CIS101" return both `[0][i]` and `[4][i]`. I've seen some info in regards to creating objects or grouping arrays, but I can't figure out how to properly apply them here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
class TimesAndInstructors{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int Courses = 5;
    final int Details = 3;

    String[][] CourseInfo = new String[Courses][Details];

    CourseInfo[0][0] = "CIS101";
    CourseInfo[0][1] = "Mon 9 a.m.";
    CourseInfo[0][2] = "Farrel";

    CourseInfo[1][0] = "CIS210";
    CourseInfo[1][1] = "Mon 11 a.m.";
    CourseInfo[1][2] = "Patel";

    CourseInfo[2][0] = "MKT100";
    CourseInfo[2][1] = "Tues 8:30 a.m.";
    CourseInfo[2][2] = "Wong";

    CourseInfo[3][0] = "ACC150";
    CourseInfo[3][1] = "Tues 6 p.m.";
    CourseInfo[3][2] = "Deitrich";

    CourseInfo[4][0] = "CIS101";
    CourseInfo[4][1] = "Fri 1 p.m.";
    CourseInfo[4][2] = "Lennon";

    System.out.println("Enter college course ID: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String CourseID = input.nextLine();
    String ClassTime;
    String Instructor;

    ClassTime = FirstClass(CourseInfo, CourseID);
    Instructor = Instructor(CourseInfo, CourseID);

    if(ClassTime!= null){
        System.out.println("Course name: " + CourseID
                + "\nProfessor name: " + Instructor
                + "\nFirst class: " + ClassTime);

    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry:"
                + "\nCourse ID is 3 letters followed by 3 numbers.");
    }
}
private static String Instructor(String[][] CourseInfo, String CourseID) {
    String Professor = null;

    boolean found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < CourseInfo.length && !found; i++){
        if (CourseInfo[i][0].equals(CourseID)){
            Professor = CourseInfo[i][2];
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return Professor;
}
private static String FirstClass(String[][] CourseInfo, String CourseID) {
    String Time = null;

    boolean found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < CourseInfo.length && !found; i++){
        if (CourseInfo[i][0].equals(CourseID)){
            Time = CourseInfo[i][1];
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return Time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt to search in the 2D array and what didn't work.

Comment: My thoughts were to incorporate something like the following as a second if before the else statement.

        if(ClassTime = CourseInfo[Courses][Details]){
        System.out.println("Course name: " + CourseID
                + "\nProfessor name: " + Instructor
                + "\nFirst class: " + ClassTime);

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ArrayList` as the return type. If it was empty then you know no match has been found. The following code is for your `Instructor` method and you can adopt other methods as well:

```
private static ArrayList<String> Instructor(String[][] courseInfo, String courseID) {
    ArrayList<String> professors = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < courseInfo.length; i++)
        if (courseInfo[i][0].equals(courseID))
            professors.add(courseInfo[i][2]);

    return professors;
}
```